# Specify width of fields in Jinja Templates

Tags: python, jinja2

Is there a way to specify the width of each field in Jinja template?

For example I want my output to be displayed like this:

```
Name           Roll  Address                      Subject1        Subject2
```

I want each field to have a width associated with it. Each field has a different width

I have found a way to do this with the help of Python formatting

```
template = "{:20} {:2} {:30} {:10} {:10}"
fields = template.format("Name", "Roll", "Address","Subject1", "Subject1")
print(fields)
```

However, I need a way to do this in Jinja2 because I have a ton of fields and some of them require conditional formatting. Is there a way to do this without having to hard-code the spaces in between?

```
{{Name}}              {{Roll}}  {{Address}}             {{Subject1}}              {{Subject2}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s a filter for percent-formatting, [`format`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#format):

```
{{'%-20s'|format(Name)}} {{'%-2s'|format(Roll)}} {{'%-30s'|format(Address)}} {{'%-10s'|format(Subject1)}} {{'%-10s'|format(Subject2)}}
```

or

```
{{'%-20s %-2s %-30s %-10s %-10s'|format(Name, Roll, Address, Sbject1, Subject2)}}
```

`%-<num>s` is a [right-padding format specifier](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) like `{:<num>}`.